# How to execute DML statements that contain semi colons using cx_oracle python lib

Tags: python, sql, database, cx-oracle

currently I execute multiple DML statements using cursor.execute() method . I split the statements using ; delimiter and pass each statement to cursor.execute() method . This worked well until I encountered some of the statements that contains semi colon in the SQL statement itself .

I have tried using cursor.executemany() method , by passing multiple statements with out splitting by semi colon . But it throws error to declare parameters value . But all the statements i execute are static , I do not need any sequence or iterations .

```
cursor.executemany(sqlCommands,1,batcherrors=True)
```

**TypeError**: expecting string, unicode or buffer object

```
cursor.executemany(sqlCommands,'',batcherrors=True)
```

**TypeError**: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement

how do handle semi colons in the SQL Statements to execute using cx_oracle python lib

Comment: can you please show your code, and possibly a fiddle with an example of your issue to enable us to help you

Comment: Thanks for the response . I found another way to split the queries using sqlparse lib . I will close this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the trailing semi-colons.  They are not part of a SQL statement and the Oracle database doesn't accept them - as you found.  The semi-colons are an indicator to some tools (like SQL*Plus) to send any preceding text to the database.

How you remove the semicolons will depend on what you are doing.   It's best to restrict your input file syntax to make life easier for yourself.   The sample setup script [`SampleEnv.py`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.0/samples/SampleEnv.py#L116-L149) works because it requires the input file statements to have a trailing slash.

cx_Oracle's `executemany()` function executes *one* statement with *many* data values.  It does not execute multiple statements.  Refer to the documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).